# Android application to transfer files using bluetooth

Tags: android

I m developing an android application to transfer file to a remote device through bluetooth.I have successfully connected devices but don't know how to proceed with transfer.Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
I can send a file using this code.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, "file:///sdcard/refresh.txt");
values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceAddress);
values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Code of BluetoothShare.java

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * Exposes constants used to interact with the Bluetooth Share manager's content
 * provider.
 */

public final class BluetoothShare implements BaseColumns {
private BluetoothShare() {
}
/**
 * The permission to access the Bluetooth Share Manager
 */
public static final String PERMISSION_ACCESS = "android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE";

/**
 * The content:// URI for the data table in the provider
 */
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp");

/**
 * Broadcast Action: this is sent by the Bluetooth Share component to
 * transfer complete. The request detail could be retrieved by app * as _ID
 * is specified in the intent's data.
 */
public static final String TRANSFER_COMPLETED_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.TRANSFER_COMPLETE";

/**
 * This is sent by the Bluetooth Share component to indicate there is an
 * incoming file need user to confirm.
 */
public static final String INCOMING_FILE_CONFIRMATION_REQUEST_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.INCOMING_FILE_NOTIFICATION";

/**
 * This is sent by the Bluetooth Share component to indicate there is an
 * incoming file request timeout and need update UI.
 */
public static final String USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT_ACTION = "android.btopp.intent.action.USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the URI of the file being
 * sent/received.
 */
public static final String URI = "uri";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the filename that the incoming file
 * request recommends. When possible, the Bluetooth Share manager will
 * attempt to use this filename, or a variation, as the actual name for the
 * file.
 */
public static final String FILENAME_HINT = "hint";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the filename where the shared file was
 * actually stored.
 */
public static final String _DATA = "_data";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the MIME type of the shared file.
 */
public static final String MIMETYPE = "mimetype";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the direction (Inbound/Outbound) of the
 * transfer. See the DIRECTION_* constants for a list of legal values.
 */
public static final String DIRECTION = "direction";

/**
 * The name of the column containing Bluetooth Device Address that the
 * transfer is associated with.
 */
public static final String DESTINATION = "destination";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the flags that controls whether the
 * transfer is displayed by the UI. See the VISIBILITY_* constants for a
 * list of legal values.
 */
public static final String VISIBILITY = "visibility";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the current user confirmation state of
 * the transfer. Applications can write to this to confirm the transfer. the
 * USER_CONFIRMATION_* constants for a list of legal values.
 */
public static final String USER_CONFIRMATION = "confirm";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the current status of the transfer.
 * Applications can read this to follow the progress of each download. See
 * the STATUS_* constants for a list of legal values.
 */
public static final String STATUS = "status";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the total size of the file being
 * transferred.
 */
public static final String TOTAL_BYTES = "total_bytes";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the size of the part of the file that
 * has been transferred so far.
 */
public static final String CURRENT_BYTES = "current_bytes";

/**
 * The name of the column containing the timestamp when the transfer is
 * initialized.
 */
public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";

/**
 * This transfer is outbound, e.g. share file to other device.
 */
public static final int DIRECTION_OUTBOUND = 0;

/**
 * This transfer is inbound, e.g. receive file from other device.
 */
public static final int DIRECTION_INBOUND = 1;

/**
 * This transfer is waiting for user confirmation.
 */
public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_PENDING = 0;

/**
 * This transfer is confirmed by user.
 */
public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_CONFIRMED = 1;

/**
 * This transfer is auto-confirmed per previous user confirmation.
 */
public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_AUTO_CONFIRMED = 2;

/**
 * This transfer is denied by user.
 */
public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_DENIED = 3;

/**
 * This transfer is timeout before user action.
 */
public static final int USER_CONFIRMATION_TIMEOUT = 4;

/**
 * This transfer is visible and shows in the notifications while in progress
 * and after completion.
 */
public static final int VISIBILITY_VISIBLE = 0;

/**
 * This transfer doesn't show in the notifications.
 */
public static final int VISIBILITY_HIDDEN = 1;

/**
 * Returns whether the status is informational (i.e. 1xx).
 */
public static boolean isStatusInformational(int status) {
    return (status >= 100 && status < 200);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the transfer is suspended. (i.e. whether the transfer
 * won't complete without some action from outside the transfer manager).
 */
public static boolean isStatusSuspended(int status) {
    return (status == STATUS_PENDING);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the status is a success (i.e. 2xx).
 */
public static boolean isStatusSuccess(int status) {
    return (status >= 200 && status < 300);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the status is an error (i.e. 4xx or 5xx).
 */
public static boolean isStatusError(int status) {
    return (status >= 400 && status < 600);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the status is a client error (i.e. 4xx).
 */
public static boolean isStatusClientError(int status) {
    return (status >= 400 && status < 500);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the status is a server error (i.e. 5xx).
 */
public static boolean isStatusServerError(int status) {
    return (status >= 500 && status < 600);
}

/**
 * Returns whether the transfer has completed (either with success or
 * error).
 */
public static boolean isStatusCompleted(int status) {
    return (status >= 200 && status < 300) || (status >= 400 && status < 600);
}

/**
 * This transfer hasn't stated yet
 */
public static final int STATUS_PENDING = 190;

/**
 * This transfer has started
 */
public static final int STATUS_RUNNING = 192;

/**
 * This transfer has successfully completed. Warning: there might be other
 * status values that indicate success in the future. Use isSucccess() to
 * capture the entire category.
 */
public static final int STATUS_SUCCESS = 200;

/**
 * This request couldn't be parsed. This is also used when processing
 * requests with unknown/unsupported URI schemes.
 */
public static final int STATUS_BAD_REQUEST = 400;

/**
 * This transfer is forbidden by target device.
 */
public static final int STATUS_FORBIDDEN = 403;

/**
 * This transfer can't be performed because the content cannot be handled.
 */
public static final int STATUS_NOT_ACCEPTABLE = 406;

/**
 * This transfer cannot be performed because the length cannot be determined
 * accurately. This is the code for the HTTP error "Length Required", which
 * is typically used when making requests that require a content length but
 * don't have one, and it is also used in the client when a response is
 * received whose length cannot be determined accurately (therefore making
 * it impossible to know when a transfer completes).
 */
public static final int STATUS_LENGTH_REQUIRED = 411;

/**
 * This transfer was interrupted and cannot be resumed. This is the code for
 * the OBEX error "Precondition Failed", and it is also used in situations
 * where the client doesn't have an ETag at all.
 */
public static final int STATUS_PRECONDITION_FAILED = 412;

/**
 * This transfer was canceled
 */
public static final int STATUS_CANCELED = 490;

/**
 * This transfer has completed with an error. Warning: there will be other
 * status values that indicate errors in the future. Use isStatusError() to
 * capture the entire category.
 */
public static final int STATUS_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 491;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of a storage issue.
 * Typically, that's because the file system is missing or full.
 */
public static final int STATUS_FILE_ERROR = 492;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of no sdcard.
 */
public static final int STATUS_ERROR_NO_SDCARD = 493;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of sdcard full.
 */
public static final int STATUS_ERROR_SDCARD_FULL = 494;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of an unspecified un-handled
 * OBEX code.
 */
public static final int STATUS_UNHANDLED_OBEX_CODE = 495;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of an error receiving or
 * processing data at the OBEX level.
 */
public static final int STATUS_OBEX_DATA_ERROR = 496;

/**
 * This transfer couldn't be completed because of an error when establishing
 * connection.
 */
public static final int STATUS_CONNECTION_ERROR = 497;

}
```

Comment: this code does not work since JellyBean beacause writing directly to a share priveder can be a security issue